# Demonstrate the following propierties (State-space representation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Having this properties:

$E[x(j)w^T(k)]=0$; $j,k\geq 0,  j\leq k$.

$E[z(j)w^T(k)]=0$; $j,k\geq 0,  j\leq k$.

Demonstrate it with the following assumptions:

- $x(k+1)=\Phi (k+1,k)x(k)+\Gamma (k+1,k)w(k)~$, $k\geq 0$; $x(0)=x_0~$
  (is State equation)
- $z(k)=H(k)x(k)+v(k),  k\geq0$ (observation equation)
- Initial state $x_0$, vector n-dimensional gaussian with cov. matrix
  $E[x_0x^T_o]=P_0$
- The process $\{w(k);k\geq 0\}$ is a white noise succession, centred,
  with cov. matrix $E[w(k)w^T(k)]=Q(k), k\geq0$

  - The process $\{v(k);k\geq 0\}$ is a white noise succession, centred,
    with cov. matrix $E[v(k)v^T(k)]=R(k), k\geq0$
- The initial state and additive noises are mutually independent.

I think it has to be done with Doob theorem but in my case is not working. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_j$ is a linear combination of $x_0$ and $w_0,...,w_{j-1}$.

Per last assumptions, these are all independent of of the vectors $w_k$, $k\ge j$.

Therefore, the claim.

Comment: I add some more information, just to know if it is right. I need some help about this, I'm quite new in stochastic systems.

Comment: What is $v_k$? The same applies, also $z_j$ is composed of data from times $<j$ that are independent of $w_k$, $k>j$.

Comment: Thanks @LutzL I have corrected this in the question area

Comment: Then $z_j$ is obviously correlated to $v_j$, but still not to $w_k$, $k\ge j$.

Comment: You're right, thank you